# Change image src from byte[]

Tags: c#, sql, database, image

I am retrieving images from a database and want a real url to the image instead of the byte array format. Is it possible to get the images url/link straight from the database? Or do I need a blob storage and take the url from there?

I am using ASP.net and SQL.

This is how I want it to be formatted (don't have to be exactly the same)

```
<img src="website/images/image36.png"/>
```

This is how it looks now, and if the image is 4k the it crashes the browser if I try to edit the source because it's to many characters

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAMAAABrrFhUAAAAM1BMVEWxvsa7xs7CzNPM1drT2t/a4OTd4+fn6+7g5enW3eLFz9W/ydC0wcnP1924xMvJ0tjk6OzcN6J1AAAED0lEQVR4AezBgQAAAACAoP2pF6kCAAAAAAAAAAC4vbvLgV3FgQBcCYHiLzT7X+28XWkermbOSeLYMd8OqAA2Ust9u20PR0z8R44l1AYX+n5G/ot01oFPG7/I/yGd23dXn/h/yZ/MoBX+gVTxLTXzD+XQ8Rl75l+YAd+wRf6lvMO+fvKCMmDclnjJ3GHaj5cdMOzgDVKHUT3xFnOzu37PCfREek6gJ9JzAj2RrhNIvNkc9uufo2r44wMKzNj4iB+M6JnP2GDDyYckmND4mAALMp8zoF/ggyLU65NPar43ABmdbwCy+d4AZHS9AfR3Q5WPO6BZ4uNmh16DAqrZZ7CDZ3GihO77BJC7/hrgtQ4cFJH1XwFeLwEKadCpUUjQ3wX4vAVPCknQKVIKdJqUskGjTjG7/iLgsQxUijmhUaCY6LsKksl5FSRXABpR0OY9gAZ9uvcAGgWFFYA6K4BAQcV7AHEFoM4KoFBQdv4UIFcAaqwAVgArgBXACmAFsAJokaJigyqB4oLz9atKoPEVDVpkviJDicqXVOhQ+JICFTpf06HBztfsmmqg30pYSN+XQORr4gpgBbACWJfgKoOrEVqt8HoMrefwuyZfMaFF4CuC/rkRbgYJFAVXoL9rsEKPzhd0KHJQ3AFNBsUNqHJS2GlrjK6DEatjUtAcUGckikkDGoVMETlAq01/A2S/J57Q7Od9mtxwfgIkRgl1+D4DBbp1v5PUZOpAhnY7HxWgXvb0CBa/Bg84Hy7e4Hu8fAR8b4EGE4LPDSCwBRqMqAIlwOGTaA6Y0cSbQAdzxRIs6Zl322BKEzgArpqBCHOiwK9B/LRDDQZtk3epMKm6aAEFEjhgVtW/fv0JlA7XCRwwrjpfP3BqfgHo74kbzDu9BxB5RfUeQFgBmDe9B0DnAXReUmBd4yXReRtAwrrMa3bYVknXZ6BnXtVgWeFlucOugzdI3ef67SfQC2+SBgxqmbeZO6zpJ29VOkypkzebFXa0xAfkBhtaFBgmrFeNfFCsUK3XzIfl2qHVOCcFzHNAoz1STNyhzAiZonIY0GMvfEHZnX58XdtgL3xV2Z1+fA3bYC9Uouy+Pr6CbdAK1SkNQvovU6X863jeOCbVmscQ3vvOTkJNNCBVPKNmGpGrs+ULRFAzjcnVyfIFImiJRqWG60ahYWXgot+kafOHK0akeXHo//xKN0E/+BGlax+RqXEE5zb5IXOTXb/9BLZJek5gTComMIIk8YOS2PADrYLiUfG6BtIf/KjD+QYgh8UbQP5PCSY/awpMRdVtt34FCoxl7vy07vsEkLv8CbDWCmR+Wpbvgoz1QpUfV+VHQdpqBiM/Lpq+AwVuQX6efB9oqhds/Ly2AlgBrAD+3XB+Ca4yiMSPS/hv/wEp/tUncVv5oQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
```

Basically what I am looking for is a src to the html image element that isn't in a weird format like byte, base64 and so on...

Comment: is `ASP.NET` you can use a handler `<img src="website/images.ashx?id=39"/>`

Comment: @fubo I dont really understand how that works. Do I have to add something to the DB? And where is the id in <img src="website/images.ashx?id=39"/> coming from?

Comment: first you have to tell what's the type to your applcation? ASP.net / MVC / .NET-Core

Comment: @fubo I am using ASP.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display imgage use url, you need save your image as a file first.

```
var imgUrl = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...";
var imageCoding = Convert.FromBase64String(imgUrl.Split(",")[1]);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("yourImage.png", imageCoding);

<img src="yourImage.png">
```